# how to count rows while joining the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join, inner-join

i have two table one is for outlets details with location and one is for no. of offers of that particular outlets and i want to join two table to display outlets and their respective offers and location also , i successfully fetch the outlets and their offers by joining the table but i want how to count the no. of offers on particular location. my sql query for joining table is

```
$sql_2="SELECT p.id,p.outlet_id,p.offer_title,p.original_price,
 p.discount,p.discount_price,p.offer_image,p.offer_details,
 o.outlet_id,o.outlet_title,o.outlet_locality,o.segment_type  
FROM products as p,outlets as o 
WHERE p.outlet_id=o.outlet_id AND o.segment_type='$category' 
GROUP BY o.outlet_locality ";
```

from above i can fectch the group of localities and i want to count the total offers and ie. ALL() and indivisual locality offers on every localities
my html is '

```
<h3>Location</h3>
  <ul class="offer-location" >
    <li class="checkbox">
      <label>
         <input type="checkbox" class="i-check">All <small>(657)</small>
      </label>
    </li>
    <?php
      foreach($qry_2 as $v2){
    ?>
        <li class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="i-check"/>
               <?php echo $v2['outlet_locality'] ?> <small>(120)</small>
          </label>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql_2="SELECT p.id,p.outlet_id,p.offer_title,p.original_price,
 p.discount,p.discount_price,p.offer_image,p.offer_details,
 o.outlet_id,o.outlet_title,o.outlet_locality,o.segment_type, count(p.outlet_id) as outletCount 
 FROM products as p,outlets as o 
 WHERE p.outlet_id=o.outlet_id AND o.segment_type='$category' 
 GROUP BY o.outlet_locality ";
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" class="i-check"><?php echo $v2['outlet_locality'] ?> <small><?php echo $v2['outletCount'] ?> </small>